# Is there a Java equivalent of Clojure's if-let?

Tags: java, clojure, null

Clojure's [if-let](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if-let) allows you to condition the binding of a value returned by a function before actually evaluating the function. This allows you to avoid evaluating a function twice (mainly for null checks) as in Java's

```
 if (somMap.get(ky) != null){
      String val = someMap.get(ky)
      //do something }
```

Is there something like if-let in Java that allows you to avoid that sort of thing?

Comment: `String val = someMap.get(ky); if (val != null) { .... }`  - java isn't exactly a feature-rich language, you know....

Comment: I'm not familiar with Clojure, but maybe the Java8 construct `String val = Optional.ofNullable(someMap.get(ky)).orElse("Default Value")` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Can be written more simply as `someMap.getOrDefault(ky, "Default value")`

Comment: @Tunaki provided the question is always about nulls coming from a map, rather than a general solution for null checking, of course.

Comment: These are all good  answers, thanks

Comment: Downvoters: This was not yet another question about null-checking in Java. Maybe I should've made it clear that I was looking for the more general use-case addressed in Clojure's if-let: syntactic sugar for conditioning the binding of a returned value of a function.  The get() if not null example was the simplest example of this use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalent ? - No, `if-let` conditional macro is unique to Conjure.

Different languages use different constructs, for example in Mathematica I could write:

```
g[x_] := 1 /; x > 0
g[x_] := -1 /; x <= 0
```

Where conditional at the end tells then the function definition is valid.

Java is not functional language. You could do several different aspects in c#, but it supports ?? operator, out and ref method parameters, lazy method bodies, etc - and java does not.

In Java you would most likely use Google Guava library (or Apache commons or ...) and ImmutableMap. Note that it disallows key ability to be **null**!

> It is preferable mainly for consistency and maintainability of your code.

Java has a concept of null save types, but it is not enforced. Similarly Java could have nullable value types in JDK10, but it does not have it currently.

---

However I imagine correct way to do this in Java is

```
String val = somMap.containsKey(ky) ? values.get(ky) : fallback;
```

and not have null keys or values. If your FORCED to deal with null keys or values then and only then I think it makes reasonable to add null checks. To ensure that program WILL fail, you can use

```
Preconditions.checkNotNull(val, "EOW | key [%s] has NULL value", val );
```

Reference : Google guava Precontitions [source](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#line.208).

Comment: It isn't unique to Clojure, it also exists in Swift, actually in swift there is even the guard let x = x else { return } version

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with doing

```
String val = someMap.get(key);
if (val != null) {
    // do something
}
```

An occasionally useful alternative is to assign the value in the condition.

```
String val;
if ((val = someMap.get(key)) != null) {
    // do something with val
}
```

This requires `val` to be declared beforehand (you cannot *declare* `val` in the condition), so this version is no better than the original in this case. It is a useful trick to know if there is another part to the `if` condition:

```
String val;
if (someMap != null && (val = someMap.get(key)) != null) {
    // do something with val
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong ? There is also nothing wrong in going from NYC to LA by walk, it's just a lack of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
    String x;
    if( (x = values.get("key")) != null) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

But I think that is less readable than either [HireCore's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643085/highcore) commented answer

```
    String x = values.get("key");
    if(x != null) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

or [RealSKeptics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic)/[Tunakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) Optional/getOrDefault.