# guard/if let in Java - declare a property or an object if it can be unwrapped

Tags: java, swift, option-type

In swift there is the `guard let` / `if let` pattern allowing us to declare an object or a property only if it can be unwrapped.

it works a follow:

```
func getMeaningOfLife() -> Int? {
    42
}

func printMeaningOfLife() {
    if let name = getMeaningOfLife() {
        print(name)
    }
}

func printMeaningOfLife() {
    guard let name = getMeaningOfLife() else {
        return
    }

    print(name)
}
```

My question here is: Is there a Java version of it ?

Comment: Java, doesn't have much functional evaluation, just closures, which even prove to be abstruse for most tasks.  So, no, there is nothing intrinsic to Java that will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No.

Apparently this syntax also exists in Clojure and according to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503383/is-there-a-java-equivalent-of-clojures-if-let/33503654#33503654) there is no way to declare a property if it can be unwrapped in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have guard/let clauses like this. The closest equivalent of your example is using [`OptionalInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalInt.html) (or [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) for objects) and its [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalInt.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.IntConsumer)) method:

```java
OptionalInt getMeaningOfLife() {
    return OptionalInt.of(42);
}

void printMeaningOfLife() {
    getMeaningOfLife().ifPresent(name -> 
            System.out.println(name));
}
```

Note that Java does have a "lesser" form of these types of clauses in the form of flow-typing using `instanceof <typeName> <variableName>` introduced with [JEP 394: Pattern Matching for instanceof](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394).

Comment: This is similar for this example but guard is much more powerful than that. you can also check guard x != 12 else { return }. Which both unwrap but also check a specific case

Comment: @Cublax It is more limited, but you could do things like `if (x.orElse(12) == 12) return;`

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that there is no such thing as a conditional declaration. What's really happening is that the conditional is introducing a new scope in which the variable is always declared, or a guard condition which short-circuits.

Java can do the same, though lexically it is not as pretty.

```
Integer getMeaningOfLife() {
    return 42;
}

void printMeaningOfLife() {
    { //this brace bracket introduces a new scope
        Integer name = getMeaningOfLife();
        if (name != null) {
            print(name);
        }
    } //closes scope
    //name is now out of scope and cannot be used
}

void printMeaningOfLife() {
    Integer name = getMeaningOfLife();
    if (name == null) {
        return;
    }
    print(name)
}
```

This is basically what you have already figured out for yourself, except maybe for the brace brackets which introduce scope in the first `printMeaningOfLife()`.